# Node js web application accepts web socket connections can you write android app to communicate without changing the node js app

Tags: android

I have a Node JS web application that runs on a Raspberry Pi.  It controls a burgular alarm so that you can remotely set/unset the alarm. I have never used Node JS before hence I really want to avoid having to change it.

I know the web page interface part uses web sockets to communicate with the Node JS backend.
Am I correct in saying I should be able to write a native Android app to communicate with the Node JS backend without having to change anything in the Node JS backend?

After some research, I have found out developing a web view app is easier. However I would like the application to be running in the background. It will monitor the messages coming from the Node JS backend and soon as the backend detects the alarm has been triggered it will play a siren like sound. Would I need to develop a native android app for such functionality?

Here is the link to the source code am using:
https://github.com/lpaolini/AccentaG4/tree/master/src/mpu